# Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.chromium.ui.base.EventForwarder

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash, android-webview, chromium

The following is from a Crashlytics report. I have no clue what any of these words mean or how they relate to my app. The phone is samsung SM-G955U (OS version 7.0).

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.chromium.ui.base.EventForwarder org.chromium.content_public.browser.WebContents.getEventForwarder()' on a null object reference
arrow_right
org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents$AwViewMethodsImpl.onDragEvent (AwContents.java:192)
com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.onDragEvent (WebViewChromium.java:777)
android.webkit.WebView.onDragEvent (WebView.java:2554)
android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent (View.java:22214)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent (ViewGroup.java:1431)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent (ViewGroup.java:1417)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent (ViewGroup.java:1417)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent (ViewGroup.java:1417)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent (ViewGroup.java:1417)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent (ViewGroup.java:1417)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent (ViewGroup.java:1417)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent (ViewGroup.java:1417)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent (ViewGroup.java:1417)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent (ViewGroup.java:1417)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent (ViewGroup.java:1417)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6314)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.-wrap11 (ViewRootImpl.java)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage (ViewRootImpl.java:4206)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

The issue was discussed here a few years ago: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479310

but I don't understand what's said here either.

Can someone please explain this crash bug?